# Forcing a specific character encoding for an Excel doc in Python

Tags: pyexcel

I'm making Excel documents in Python, using PyExcel for now.

My specific problem is that when people using Excel open one of these documents, it opens in a weird character encoding, when I want it to decode in UTF-8.

Is there a way using PyExcel that I can give Excel a hint of what decoding I want to use? And if not PyExcel, something in Python? I'd rather not have to write a note to the users telling them to change their settings.

Comment: I've used openpyxl with pandas to import to xlsx format. and it works well with utf-8.

Comment: It works just by default? Or do you specify UTF-8 somewhere?

Comment: by default, I has postgresql with utf-8 data and do something like frame = pd.read_sql_table("restaurants", uri, chunksize=50000) and then save to exel with frame.to_excel() without even set utf-8 into config and it works well, python (automatically) convert to unicode and then unicode save to excel without issues. I use python3.6 and all other just via pip.